# Display data from taxonomy using Ektron CMS with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, taxonomy, ektron

I am trying display the content from taxonomy by using Ektron CMS with ASP .Net

By using the taxonomy path i got the id and trying to display the content.
But i am getting content as null.

Please let me know the possible solutions to solve this.
Waiting for experts answers.

Thanks,

Comment: What version of Ektron are you using? Can you share some code?

Answer (score 1):

In my development environment, I have the following taxonomy:

```
const string eventsTaxonomyPath = "\\Upcoming Events";
const long eventsTaxonomyId = 89;
```

It sounds like you already found this method (or something like it) in what I like to call the "Legacy API":

```
var taxonomyApi = new Ektron.Cms.API.Content.Taxonomy();
var taxonomyId = taxonomyApi.GetTaxonomyIdByPath(eventsTaxonomyPath);
```

Without any info on what version you're on, I'll assume it's a recent (8.5+) version.  The Framework API makes it really easy to get the content from a given taxonomy.  Below are a couple of ways that work on v9.0 and will most likely work in anything 8.5+ -- in the [developer briefing webcast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xiQxAxRmGg) the only major change for the Framework API in v9 was the inclusion of the e-commerce namespace.

Getting the full taxonomy tree via the `TaxonomyManager`:

```
var taxonomyItemManager = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.Organization.TaxonomyManager();
var taxData = taxonomyItemManager.GetTree(eventsTaxonomyId, includeItems: true);
```

Getting all the content recursively from a given taxonomy folder via the `ContentManager`:

```
var contentManager = new Ektron.Cms.Framework.Content.ContentManager();
var criteria = new ContentTaxonomyCriteria();
criteria.AddFilter(eventsTaxonomyPath, true);
criteria.ReturnMetadata = true;
var content = contentManager.GetList(criteria);
```

The potential downside to the `ContentManager` way is that you lose the hierarchical taxonomy structure.  The upside to using the `ContentManager` is that you can tell it to include all the metadata for each content block.  That's not possible with the `TaxonomyManager` or `TaxonomyItemManager`.

Comment: See also the documentation here: http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/edr/web/edr.htm#FrameworkAPI/Organization/TaxonomyManager.htm

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the "Get Content By Taxonomy" function you are using by default does not fetch the content. You can either-

a) Use the ID to get the content via the content manager API
b) Investigate if the function you are using has an override to include content.